# NSDateFormatter dateFromString behaviour changed in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, nsdateformatter

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    return [dateFormat dateFromString:text];
```

where text is 9:16 AM used to return a date starting from 1970 in iOS6 its returning a date like this

2000-01-01 09:16:00 +0000

is this a bug? anyway to switch to old vehaviour

Comment: If it's not in the iOS 6 Release Notes or the API Diffs then it's a bug. You could investigate NSDateFormatterBehaviour to see if this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on solution is to simply add "1970" to time text and then add "yyyy" to format but that seems kludgy

Answer (score 0):

They've definitely changed *something* in iOS 6 with the date parsing.  I already submitted a bug to Apple about it.  There's noting in the release notes about any NSDateFormatter changes.  Also see [my similar bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774433/ios-6-1-nsdateformatter-has-changed-since-ios-5-broken-parsing) around this parsing I added today.