# iOS 6.1 NSDateFormatter has changed since iOS 5 - broken parsing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdateformatter

Our iOS iPhone app contains this code which produced a valid NSDate object below named **resultDate** in iOS 5:

```
    static NSDateFormatter *invariantFmt = nil;
    if (!invariantFmt) {
        invariantFmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        [invariantFmt setLocale:locale];
        [locale release];
        [invariantFmt setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [invariantFmt setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    NSDate *resultDate = [invariantFmt dateFromString:@"08/04/2010 10:43:39 AM"];
```

After upgrading to XCode 4.6 and iOS 6.1, that code now gives a nil for resultDate, so something has changed with what they use to parse.  The release notes says nothing about NSDateFormatter changing.  Internet research has turned up only that they *might* have changed to use a newer Unicode UTS Locale parsing standard.  Obviously they changed *something*.  After twiddling with code and taking a known valid NSDate object and applying the same NSDateFormatter settings to get a NSString, I find that iOS 6.1 likes this string instead: @"08/04/2010, 10:43:39 AM"

The only difference being that extra comma after the date portion.  Using that in iOS 6.1 gives back a valid date with the same above code.  Anyone seeing this and understand why that's different or if that's an ok Unicode change or a Apple bug?

Comment: You should probably file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Or should I stop using the date "styles" (short, medium, long) and go with exact formats, like calling setDateFormat instead?  Doing that seems to work in this case in both iOS versions.

Comment: Wouldn't that make i18n difficult though?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  We were trying to follow the Apple recommended way to handle incoming dates, converting them to an invariant (POSIX english) locale format, then sending them to the parser with those styles.  Well look where that got us  :(

Comment: Welcome to the machine...

Comment: For what it's worth, I DID send an official bug report.  Even if I shouldn't have been using the styles, I'd like to know know why the behavior is different

Comment: I have the same problem.  on iOS 7, the comma is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format styles should only be used to convert `NSDate` objects to text to display to the user. When parsing a date string in a known format, you must use a specific format, never the styles. The use of the `en_US_POSIX` locale is used to ensure that the format you specify isn't tweaked by the OS based on user preferences such as the 24-hour time setting.

So, as you suspected, you need to remove the two calls to set the date and time styles and replace them with a call to set a specific format that matches your known date/time string you need to parse.

Comment: Doesn't explain why this behavior changed from iOS versions, but I agree with your logic

Comment: Most likely the comma is a new behavior when combining a date and a time. This stuff evolves or gets fixed over time which enforces the idea that you must used a fixed format and not styles when dealing with fixed format date strings.

Comment: is your, likely correct, philosophy in the Date Formatting Apple docs?  I must have missed that.  I did read that thing years ago.  Guess not well enough :)

Comment: Check out [Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html). Though my statement is more based on experience than a specific sentence in the docs.

Comment: Also, you should set the date format only once when initializing the date formatter. I guess you're caching the date formatter for performance reasons, but not the allocation, but setting the date format instead slows things down.

Comment: Interesting, Apple recommends caching them, but are you saying it's better to make a bunch of them if you will have different formatting needs instead of changing the cached on by calling setDateFormat?  Right now we just cache a couple based on a couple locales and then if the user wants a different format we call setDateFormat.  Is that bad?  The alternative would be to make a NSDateFormatter for every possible format, which for us wouldn't be an option since the user can decide at runtime what format to change to and it could be anything Unicode supports.

Comment: @stonedauwg I believe he was saying that you should set the format of the date formatter inside the `if` block, not outside.

Comment: After reading the docs, you and Fabian are correct, sounds like the approach for performance considerations would be to in fact alloc and set everything and leave it alone and just use it.  I'll have to see if that approach will work for us.  I'd upvote both of you if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not output a formatted Date to a file, and later want to parse it back.
A Date should be stored as long value UTC (with or without additional TimeZone offset).
Only in the last moment, before visualizing a Date to UI it should be formatted and local time applied.

This not only i smy experience, it it is also stated in Apple DateFormatting Doku.

Comment: We are not outputting it to a file.  It is getting sent to us from a service already formatted like this.  I agree in general UTC is best to pass around but we are at the mercy of a legacy service in this case.